# Public search engine which index HTML tags

Tags: html, search-engines, html5

Do you know a public search engine which allows search on HTML tags?

The usage will be to search websites with HTML5 tags such as `<canvas>` being able to search over the class names could also be useful.

Comment: Either WHATWG or the W3C listed the most used elements in a table not too long ago but I don't recall how they came up with that. It was done using some form of visiting each site and analyzing the contents but I don't know if that program is publicly available.

Answer (score 1):

There once was a [website from Google](http://developers.google.com/webmasters/state-of-the-web/?hl=de-DE). Sadly this doesn't work anymore! Maybe you could contact them?

You could also try to search in [this website](http://w3schools.com/).

I also found on Google [this](http://trends.builtwith.com/docinfo/HTML-5-Specific-Tags) but this is not free, as I could see.

Otherwise, I don't know a tool that can lookup/search HTML tags! I also don't know anyone, even I know a lot of web developers!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but may be [this](http://www.hostcompanies.com/freecode.htm). You may be able to do this within the [Opera browser](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/mama/) too.